# authorization form show only one time

Tags: android, android-activity

I have Activity with the authorization form, after user authentication creating new Activity.
Next, close the application and start again. Again, a window with the authorization form.
How to make that opened immediately following window after window with authorization if the user has previously logged on?

p.s Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

I would structure the app differently.  I would start the app with your "next" activity - the actual app functionality.  In its `onCreate`, I would check whether the authorisation has been completed in the past.  If yes, just continue with the app.  If not, then open a dialog or start another activity for authentication.

Comment: Thank you! It's a good idea! But how I can check whether the authorisation has been completed in the past?

Comment: @gabber How were you going to do it in your case?  In your original design plan, how would you decide whether or not to move directly to the second activity?  Use exactly same logic.